# User-Movie Ratings

Tags: data-request, film

Is it possible to get ratings per user, per movie, for Hollywood movies?

For example, OMDb API and themoviedb let users rate each movie. Can I get per-user, per movie ratings for a DB like this?

Comment: Anonymised, I assume...

Comment: I expect it to be. It makes no difference to me, but certainly a huge difference to everyone else up the chain (data provider, ratings collector, users...etc)

Comment: Netflix released a large set of such information ages ago, but, as the answer below notes, better sources now exist.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [the MovieLens Datasets](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-20m-README.html) helpful. Here's how they describe the structure of their ratings data file:

> All ratings are contained in the file ratings.csv. Each line of this file after the header row represents one rating of one movie by one user, and has the following format:
>
> userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
>
> The lines within this file are ordered first by userId, then, within user, by movieId.
>
> Ratings are made on a 5-star scale, with half-star increments (0.5 stars - 5.0 stars).
>
> Timestamps represent seconds since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970.

Cheers!